# Inner Loop design for webscraping

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I want to import restaurant data like Restaurant name, phone number, website & address to excel but unfortunately, I am getting sponsored results & also not getting website & full address as it in on the inner page when we click on the hotel name. I with some help at platforms have created a code using but it is not helping out. Please rectify the issue in my code. Website:https://www.yelp.com/searchcflt=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start="
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument, page&, I&

    For page = 0 To 1 ' this is where you change the last number for the pages to traverse
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL & page * 30, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("[class*='searchResult']")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .Item(I).outerHTML
                On Error Resume Next
                r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='heading--h3'] > a").innerText
                Cells(r, 2) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > [class*='display--inline-block']").innerText
               ' Cells(r, 3) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > address").innerText
                'Cells(r, 4) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > address").NextSibling.innerText
               'Inner loop creation
                Cells(r, 5) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > website").href ' Extract from window after clicking on hotel name
                Cells(r, 6) = Htmldoc.querySelector("[class*='container'] > fulladdress").innerText ' Extract from window after clicking on hotel name
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next I
        End With
    Next page
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the ways which will let you parse the results from it's inner pages. I can't access that webpage anymore to assist you further. However, give it a shot. I suppose it will work:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=restaurants&find_loc=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start="
    Const base$ = "https://www.yelp.com"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim oTitle$, oPhone As Object, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim R&, newUrl$, I&, oWeb As Object, page&, oAddress As Object

    [A1:D1] = [{"Name","Phone","Address","Website"}]

    For page = 1 To 3   'this is where you change the last number for this script to traverse
        With Http
            .Open "GET", URL & page * 30, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("[class*='searchResult'] [class*='heading--h3'] > a")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                If Not InStr(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "/adredir?") > 0 Then
                    oTitle = .item(I).innerText
                    newUrl = Replace(.item(I).getAttribute("href"), "about:", base)
                    With Http
                        .Open "GET", newUrl, False
                        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                        .send
                        Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                    End With

                    R = R + 1: Cells(R + 1, 1) = oTitle

                    Set oPhone = Htmldoc.querySelector(".biz-phone")
                    If Not oPhone Is Nothing Then
                        Cells(R + 1, 2) = oPhone.innerText
                    End If

                    Set oAddress = Htmldoc.querySelector(".map-box-address")
                    If Not oAddress Is Nothing Then
                        Cells(R + 1, 3) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(oAddress.innerText)
                    End If

                    Set oWeb = Htmldoc.querySelector(".biz-website > a")
                    If Not oWeb Is Nothing Then
                        Cells(R + 1, 4) = oWeb.innerText
                    End If
                End If
            Next I
        End With
    Next page
End Sub
```

Btw, the ads have been kicked out.

Comment: some restaurant names cell appearing blank in sheet don't know why and website address is also needed dear

Comment: Check out the update. Wesite field added along with the headers. Trying to fix the titles but I get blocked every now and then.

Comment: Yes, website issue is fine, how to cover a range of pages i.e. from 1 to 2 page & again titles issue is there...

Comment: Pagination also has been taken care of. You need to find any way to fix the title. I'm getting 404 error as the site has blocked me. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks, dear, you have made it much easier. I am trying to find title issue now

Comment: Everything is done. Check it out one more time @werdakloi.

Comment: Can we somehow speed up the code as for 1 to 10 pages it is taking a lot of time..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the free API to get the top 50 from the [business_search](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search) endpoint. Pass sort parameter in query string to get top rated.

Use a json parser, such as [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to handle the response. After installing the code from that link in a standard module called JsonConverter, go to VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

API instructions are [here](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search). You need to set up a [test app](https://www.yelp.com/developers/v3/manage_app), which requires some basic user info, and verify your email. You will then receive an API key for [authentication](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication) which is passed in the authorization header as shown below.

There is other info returned which you can parse if wanted.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTopRestuarants()
    Dim json As Object, headers(), r As Long, c As Long
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=restuarant&location=san-francisco&limit=50&sort_by=rating", False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer yourAPIkey"
        .send
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("businesses")
        headers = Array("Restaurant name", "phone", "website", "address")
        Dim results(), item As Object
        ReDim results(1 To json.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
        For Each item In json
            r = r + 1
            results(r, 1) = item("name")
            results(r, 2) = item("phone")
            results(r, 3) = item("url")
            Dim subItem As Variant, address As String
            address = vbNullString
            For Each subItem In item("location")("display_address")
                address = address & Chr$(32) & subItem
            Next
            results(r, 4) = Trim$(address)
        Next
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

Example top 20 of 50 returned:

[image]

---

**Caveat emptor**

*Note that specifying the sort_by is a suggestion (not strictly enforced) to Yelp's search, which considers multiple input parameters to return the most relevant results. For example, the rating sort is not strictly sorted by the rating value, but by an adjusted rating value that takes into account the number of ratings, similar to a Bayesian average. This is to prevent skewing results to businesses with a single review.*